# IIS replaces redirect status header from PHP with 302 Redirect

Tags: php, iis-7, fastcgi, 301-redirect

I hope I am posting this in the correct place...

I'm having an issue with a 301 redirect in php.  Looking at the headers, if I do a simple 301 redirect, it actually appears as a 302 redirect which is not what I am after.

This is the php code:

```
header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
header('Location: newurl');
```

It is running on the latest version of php, IIS7 and uses the FastCGI module (which is apparently where this bug could exist).

A quick Google finds other people with the same problem, but no actual solution.
http://www.mombu.com/php/bugs-forum/t-301-redirect-returning-302-instead-3090775.html
http://forums.iis.net/p/1158431/1907156.aspx

Many thanks! Paul

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your first line:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently");
```

I'm going to make a bet that IIS isn't recognizing the `Status:` token.